# how to restore number after modulo

Tags: java, methods, modulo

How can I cache the original digits I removed in a modulo action, so they can subsequently be restored after substituting a digit with another digit?

Example:

```
Public void setDigit(int number, int place, int newdigit) {
    Int num = number;
    Int k = place;
    Int newDigit = newdigit;

    For(int x = 0; x<k; x++) {
        Num/=10;
    }

    Num%=10;
    Num = newDigit 
}
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code will not compile. Where did you get it?

Comment: You want to keep the elements of the equation? Example  : (9% 2 = 4 + 1) here you keep The divided number (9) and the result (4) ? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: not exactly I will give example, user choose number 35467 and he want to change the digit in second place which mean the digit 4, with the number 2 , what should i do to bring 6,7 after i replaced the digit ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, if `num = 1234`for example you want to find `123` when you take the modulo of 10.

To do this you can simply use `num / x` where `num` is an `int` and `x` is an `int` which euqls the modulo you just used.

So in this case `num %= 10` gives `num = 4`. But if we did `num / 10` first then we would get `123`.

Comment: But how can i get the number i modulo back? And what if i want to change number 2?